# Reset values to zero on clicking reset, and on the bases of values generated i want a speedometer showing temp and speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!saample.html>

<html>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frame src="frame1.php">
<frame src="k3.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

```html
<!frame1.php>

<?php
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['bttn'] ) && !empty( $_POST['type'] ) ){

            $type=$_POST['type'];
            $bttn=$_POST['bttn'];


            $_SESSION['buttonClicked'][ $type ]=$bttn;

            exit( json_encode( $_SESSION['buttonClicked'] ) );
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Set Colours of Buttons</title>
        <style>
        .green{
            background-color: green;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .blue{
            background-color: blue;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .yellow{
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: black;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .red{
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        input[type='button']{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            margin:0 0.25rem;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var colours={
                    1:'red',
                    2:'blue',
                    3:'green',
                    4:'yellow'
                };
                var flags={ 
                    passive:true,
                    capture:false
                };
                function setcolours(e){
                    var _class=this.dataset.class;
                    var col=this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"][data-class="'+_class+'"]');

                    /* Clear previous colour classes assigned */
                    col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                        Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                            e.classList.remove( c );
                        });
                    });

                    /* Add colour class to any element with a value equal to or less that selected button value */
                    for( var i=this.value; i > 0; i-- ){
                        try{
                            if( col[ i - 1 ].nodeType==1 )col[ i - 1 ].classList.add( colours[ col[ i - 1 ].value ] )
                        }catch( err ){
                            console.info( err );
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    ajax( this.value, this.dataset.type );
                }
                function ajax( value, type ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
                            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=this.response;
                        }
                    };
                    var params='bttn='+value+'&type='+type;
                    xhr.open( 'post', location.href, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( params );
                }
                function bindEvents(e){
                    var col = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
                    if( col && col.length > 0 ){
                        for( var n in col ){
                            if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                                col[ n ].addEventListener( 'click', setcolours.bind( col[ n ] ), flags );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, flags );
            }());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action='chk.php' method='post'>
            <div align="left">Temperature </div>

            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="left">Humidity</div>
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="left">Number of people </div>
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
            <input type='reset' value='reset' onclick="window.location='k7.php'">
        </form>
  
          <pre id='results'></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<! frame2.php>

 <html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonClicked = "";

    $("input").on('click', function(){

      var thisDiv = $(this).val();
      buttonClicked = thisDiv;
      var classToAdd = "";

      $.post("chk.php", { buttonClicked: buttonClicked});

      console.log(thisDiv);
      switch(thisDiv){
        case "1": classToAdd = "red";
          break;   
        case "2":
          classToAdd = "blue";
          break;
        case "3":
          classToAdd = "green";
          break;
        case "4":
          classToAdd = "yellow";
          break;
    case "5":
          classToAdd = "pink";
          break;
        
        default:
          break;
      };

      $("input").each(function(index,value){
        var actualClass = $(value).attr("class");
        if(index < thisDiv){
          $(value).addClass(classToAdd).removeClass(actualClass);
        }else{
        if(actualClass != "button"){
            $(value).addClass("button").removeClass(actualClass);
          }
          
        }

        
        
      });
      
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
  $_SESSION["buttonClicked"] = $_POST["buttonClicked"];
  echo '$_SESSION["buttonClicked"]';
?>
<style>
.green{
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
</style>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var colours={
                    1:'red',
                    2:'blue',
                    3:'green',
                    4:'yellow'
                };
                var flags={ 
                    passive:true,
                    capture:false
                };
                function setcolours(e){
                    var _class=this.dataset.class;
                    var col=this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"][data-class="'+_class+'"]');

                    /* Clear previous colour classes assigned */
                    col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                        Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                            e.classList.remove( c );
                        });
                    });

                    /* Add colour class to any element with a value equal to or less that selected button value */
                    for( var i=this.value; i > 0; i-- ){
                        try{
                            if( col[ i - 1 ].nodeType==1 )col[ i - 1 ].classList.add( colours[ col[ i - 1 ].value ] )
                        }catch( err ){
                            console.info( err );
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    ajax( this.value, this.dataset.type );
                }
                function ajax( value, type ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
                            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=this.response;
                        }
                    };
                    var params='bttn='+value+'&type='+type;
                    xhr.open( 'post', location.href, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( params );
                }
                function bindEvents(e){
                    var col = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
                    if( col && col.length > 0 ){
                        for( var n in col ){
                            if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                                col[ n ].addEventListener( 'click', setcolours.bind( col[ n ] ), flags );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, flags );
            }());
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
  <div align="left">Temperature </div>
  <form action='chk.php' method='post'>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="4">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="5">
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <div align="left">Speed </div>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="1">
 <input type="button" class="button" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="4">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="5">
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Firstly,on clicking the reset button, the last generated values must b erased.
secondly, this program generates three outputs (i.e), temperature, humidity, and number of people. on the bases of these values i want the second half of my frame to display these changes on a speedometer. like when i give my input as temperature=1, humidity=1, and number of people=1, them then speedometer for two components being speed and temperature must b able to show to show these dynamic changes on clicking submit button. I could not make a speedometer though. what am i supposed do next?? I stuck! Any kind of possible help can work out. Thanks           MY Code: "sample.html"

Comment: where are `k3.html` and `chk.php`

Comment: there the web pages that do the background calculations for conditions.               THE CONDITIONS ARE:
                
                       FRAME 1(input)           =   FRAME 2(Output)
                
                (temp=1,humidity=1,ppl=1)=(temp=5, speed=1)
                (temp=1,humidity=1,ppl=2)=(temp=5, speed=1)
                (temp=1,humidity=1,ppl=3)=(temp=4, speed=2)
                (temp=1,humidity=1,ppl=4)=(temp=4, speed=2)
                
 and many combinations such. i want the feilds to b colored on these combinaions